# Looping using setInterval

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a counter that counts from 10 to 0 using JavaScript with a loop function and `setInterval` but this does not work for me:

```js
function count() {
  var i;

  for (i = numbers.textContent; 0 <= i; i--) {
    numbers.textContent = i;
  }

}

setInterval(count, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countDown">10</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
parseInt(numbers.textContent)
```

And there are many more:

1. You need a global variable.
2. You don't need a `for` loop for this.
3. Change the condition.

```html
<div id="countDown">10</div>
<script>
  var numbers = document.getElementById('countDown');
  var interval = setInterval(count, 1000);
  function count() {
    var count = parseInt(numbers.textContent);
    count--;
    if (count == 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    numbers.textContent = count;
  }
</script>
```

---

If you want to see it by loops, you can do using `setTimeout`:

```html
<div id="countDown">10</div>
<script>
  var numbers = document.getElementById('countDown');
  function count() {
    var count = parseInt(numbers.textContent);
    count--;
    numbers.textContent = count;
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= parseInt(numbers.textContent); i++)
    setTimeout(count, 1000 * i);
</script>
```

Comment: sir can you do this count by a loop or forloop just to make me think why i try to looping the counts    ........... as practice to me

Comment: @waelthepro You don't need the loops. Loops quickly run (so you can't see the change).

Comment: thank you sir very mutch .... if you can do the loops by setInterval i will be so happy ... thank you any way

Comment: @waelthepro That's the maximum possible. Your `setInterval` kind of a `for` loop so you don't have the need to use both. I don't think your question makes sense after all have answered and assumed the same way as me. If you can get the original question, may be there's something that you weren't able to communicate properly, we might be able to try to answer. Let me know if you have got something.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a for loop inside `setInterval`

```js
var numbers = document.getElementById('countDown');

function count() {

    var i;
    if(numbers.textContent>0)
      numbers.textContent=numbers.textContent-1;
    else 
      clearInterval(handle);
    /*for(i=numbers.textContent; 0<=i; i--){
        console.log(i)
        numbers.textContent= i;
    }*/

}


var handle= setInterval(count, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countDown">10</div>
```

Comment: This goes beyond `-1`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar just fixed it

Comment: Yep. Saw.. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar also cleared the interval as its not required after 0 as you did which is great !!

Answer (score 0):

the first time `count` is called, the `for` loop will run till `numbers.textContent` is 0(and it's so fast that your eyes just missed that change on the page), and the 2nd call, 3rd call is just iterate around 0, nothing is changed.

BTW, after your counting is finished(or maybe you should give it a stop condition, reference to the DOC), you should unregister the `interval`, cause it never end by default.